# How to find the solutions of multiple nonlinear equations in R using the fsolve function

Tags: r, equation

I want to use the “fsolve” function solution of nonlinear equations, equations and code is as follows, but I can only use “fsolve”function only to find the solution of a set of nonlinear equations, for example, I have three number in the A and B coefficient（A_coeff and B_coeff）, according to my idea is that each number after formulas to calculate a set of solution, then three, there should be three sets of solution, what can I do to achieve them

```
A_coeff<-c(177506.9,177639.3,178039.4)
B_coeff<-c(0.0003485474,0.0005155126,0.0004671370)
C_coeff<-5.511464
D_coeff<-23.39138
E_coeff<-5.0866e+17
F_coeff<-0.9732414
library('pracma')
Para_fun <- function(temp1) {
  new <- sqrt((4*temp1-1)/3)
  return(new)
}
Para_fun2<- function(temp1) {
  new2 <- ceiling(temp1/C_coeff)
  return(new2)
}
F_try<- function(x){
  s_actual <- x[1]
  K_actual <- x[2]
  n_tube <- x[3]
  c( A_coeff/K_actual-s_actual,
     (B_coeff+F_coeff/(E_coeff/Para_fun(n_tube)^(2/3))^0.25)^-1-K_actual,
     Para_fun2(s_actual)*D_coeff-n_tube)}
x0_xinitial_value<- c(20,2000,20)
X_result<- fsolve(F_try, x0_xinitial_value)
X_result$x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to solve the set of equations for each pair of `A_coeff` and `B_coeff` with a loop.

Redefine function `F_try` as (where I have rewritten the code to make easier to read and less confusing)

```
F_try<- function(x,k){
  s_actual <- x[1]
  K_actual <- x[2]
  n_tube <- x[3]
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  y[1] <- A_coeff[k]/K_actual-s_actual
  y[2] <- (B_coeff[k]+F_coeff/(E_coeff/Para_fun(n_tube)^(2/3))^0.25)^-1-K_actual
  y[3] <- Para_fun2(s_actual)*D_coeff-n_tube
```

y
}

The argument `k` is the index of the vector of coefficient `A_coeff` and `B_coeff`.

If you try this like so

```
X_result <- matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=3)
xstart <- x0_xinitial_value
for( k in 1:3){
    z <- fsolve(F_try, xstart,k=k)
    X_result[k,] <- z$x
}
X_result
```

you will get an error message

```
Error in if (norm(s, "F") < tol || norm(as.matrix(ynew), "F") < tol) break :
```

with message

```
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: fsolve -> broyden
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt((4 * temp1 - 1)/3) : NaNs produced
Execution halted
```

It is no immediately clear what is wrong and why the error occurs.

There is another package `nleqslv` which gives more insight into what is going wrong.

You can use it like this

```
library(nleqslv)
X_result <- matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=3)
xstart <- x0_xinitial_value
for( k in 1:3){
    z <- nleqslv(xstart,F_try,k=k)
    X_result[k,] <- z$x
}
X_result
```

Inspecting `X_result` shows that the third solution is most likely wrong.
Cutting a long story short it appears that for `k=3` and the starting values you provided the algorithms cannot find a solution.

A solution is to make the starting value for each `k` equal to the solution for the previous `k`.  Like so

```
X_result <- matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=3)
xstart <- x0_xinitial_value
for( k in 1:3){
    z <- nleqslv(xstart,F_try,k=k)
    X_result[k,] <- z$x
    xstart <- z$x
}
X_result
```

resulting in

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  72.60480 2444.837 327.4793
[2,] 102.59563 1731.451 444.4362
[3,]  94.16426 1890.732 421.0448
```

It is advisable to check the exit code of `nleqslv` for each row of this matrix
to make sure that a solution was found.